# how to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in order to check some folder before others

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

For my application, I used special version of library which is copied to /opt/lib folder.
when I run my app, if from the terminal, I do:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lib` first,
then

my app runs well.
otherwise, it will use the wrong library from /usr/lib

How can I add /opt/lib to the system, then it will check my path before /usr/lib?
Thanks.

LJ

Answer (score 0):

The way $PATH is searched is directories listed at the beginning of $PATH take precedence over those that come later. So make sure you have the right order.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `/opt/lib` to the `/etc/ld.so.conf` file (or a file in the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` directory) and then running `ldconfig` (as root) will configure the system linker to include that path in its searches. I believe anything in there will come before the defaults paths of `/lib` and `/usr/lib` (at least according to the man page I am looking at). Ordering beyond that, between locations specified in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` files, is a different question but is probably just file read order dependent.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this, but not work. After I add a file to /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ and run ldconfig, I still got the wrong library in /usr/lib.  I also tried to modify /etc/ld.so.conf file, add /opt/lib to it, not work either. So far, the only way works for me is to do export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lib from command line. Any idea? Thanks a lot

Comment: Define "not work". If you ask ldconfig to show you the cache do you see your library (under `/opt/lib`) in the cache?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all replies. 
I just found out how to do this for my situation:

Add two lines to the .bashrc file in home directory:

```
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lib
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

then restarts a new terminal, run ldd my app, the library is linked to /opt/lib.

Hope this is useful.
Thanks 
LJ

Comment: `ldd` doesn't tell you what your app is linked to. That's not how things work. It tells you what the runtime linker will use **at that moment** to link the library/binary.